# Android Studio ошибка запуска приложения на своем девайсе (Xiaomi)

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь запустить приложение на своем девайсе но постоянно выскакивает эта ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это типовая ошибка для телефонов **Xiaomi**, пишут, что надо сделать так:

1. Активировать режим разработчика на телефоне: Настройки->О телефоне->и нажать 7 раз на MIUI версию
2. Идем опять в настройки, дополнительные настройки, настройки разработчика и включаем отладку через USB
3. Подключаем телефон к компу - при первом подключении на телефоне выскочит уведомление с просьбой авторизовать подключенный комп - принимаем авторизацию
4. Идем обратно в настройки разработчика, включаем оптимизацию MIUI и выключаем ее - после этого телефон перезагрузится.
5. Пробуем еще раз.

Пункты 1-2 - самоочевидные, 3-4 важные пункты (шаг 3 также актуален для Samsung'ов) - 4 - чисто для Xiaomi

[Цынк](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6499)

**P.S.**

> В общем то он говорит, что такое приложение уже стоит, и если вы нажмете "ок" - он удалит установленное приложение вместе с данынми, относящимися к этому приложению и установит то, что вы хотите.

Неправда, пишет, что возможно поможет снос приложения.

> Если не ошибаюсь это означает, что приложение с таким именем и пакетом уже есть на устройстве, но подписано другими ключами. Удалите его через Настройки андроида и можно будет ставить с Ее

Ошибаетесь - совсем не об этом пишет.

Comment: Отключил оптимизацию MUI и все заработало, спасибо вам!

Comment: @Anton Обращайтесь :)

Answer (score 1):

В общем то он говорит, что такое приложение уже стоит, и если вы нажмете "ок" - он удалит установленное приложение вместе с данынми, относящимися к этому приложению и установит то, что вы хотите.

Answer (score 1):

Xiaomi node 3 pro MIUI 8.5.3.0.
Была такая же проблема.
Решилась без отключения оптимизации.
Телефон от компьютера отключен.
В "Настройки для разработчиков" должны быть включены:
 - режим разработчика; 
 - отладка по USB; 
 - Установка через USB. 
Подключаем, проверяем диспетчер устройств. Ваше устройство должно быть распознано как тот или иной "Interface". Если это неизвестное устройство -  ставим дрова из гугла.
...
По факту моя проблема заключалась в собственной невнимательности в настройках.

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь это означает, что приложение с таким именем и пакетом уже есть на устройстве, но подписано другими ключами. Удалите его через Настройки андроида и можно будет ставить с Ее

Comment: С таким именем ничего нет

Comment: Места хватает на устройстве?

Comment: 16 гб еще доступно

Comment: Приложение  это в первый раз ставите на устройство?

Comment: Да , вот только недавно разобрался с драйверами

Comment: Глупый вопрос, но включён ли режим разработчика?

Comment: И ставится ли приложение если его сбросить в виде APK на устройство

Comment: Да режим включен и отладка по USB тоже

Comment: В виде  АРК еще не пробывал, хотел только посмотреть как приложение на телефоне смотрится