# Не устанавливается программа на Android 6.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Какие могут причины отказа в установке, через USB, в режиме отладки, на устройство с Android 6.0.1. (Xiaomi Redmi 3S)
Сообщение AndroidStudio:

```
Installation failed with message Failed to establish session.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an 
existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

Установка на другие устройства, например с Android 5 проходит.
С помощью Genymotion, на Android 6 все нормально.

Comment: Приложение там уже стоит? И попробуйте заново активировать насойки разработчика, отладку там по УСБ и т.д.

Comment: E:\AndroidProject\Sort\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.ka_ba.sort
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs

Comment: приложение не стоит. пробовал перенести его через файл, установил, при запуске вылетает. сейчас удалено.

Comment: настройки разработчика отключал и включал, и прочие настройки тоже.

Comment: Попробуйте очистить проект (Build -> Clean Project) и отребилдить его (Build -> Rebuild Project).

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос [обсуждался в этой ветке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/653328/android-studio-ошибка-запуска-приложения-на-своем-девайсе-xiaomi)

Comment: Благодарю. Все заработало! Оказалось это особенность Xiaomi Redmi 3S.